# QUARKUS: Set Environment variable to get value from a linuxcommand

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

In Quarkus, You can define environment variables that will represent as configuration to your Quarkus app. For example:

`DATABASE_PASSWORD=test123`

Outside the quarkus app, there is a file that contains a password. The content of this file (being the password) needs to be set to a property in the quarkus app.

Would it be possible to define an environment variable (i.e. a property) that runs a 'cat' command on that file (as the quarkus app is running in a linux environment) and the value is stored in that environment variable?

e.g.

DATABASE_PASSWORD=`cat /var/common/database_secret.txt`

Is this possible? If not would anyone be able to make suggestions for an alternative solution (where we have to have a property whereby the value is from the contents of a file)?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can implement a `ConfigSource` that reads data from a file.

Comment: @LadIcek perhaps some example code would help and be useful as an answer